# The name ... does not exist in the current context VS 2017 to VS 2019

Tags: c#, html

I have checked out a working project that was built using VS 2017. I'm using VS2019. When I open the project I get CS0103 The name 'AdLoggedOnPerson' does not exist in the current context.

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ResponsiveMasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="disabilitystatus.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmployeeToolBox.disabilitystatus" %>
```

```html
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <p class="paragraph" style="margin-left: .5in; text-indent: .5in">
                    <u><%=AdLoggedOnPerson.FullName%></u>
                </p>
            </div>
```

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using MailMessage = System.Net.Mail.MailMessage;
using MailPriority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority;
using EmployeeToolBox.App_Code;

namespace EmployeeToolBox
{
    public partial class disabilitystatus : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public AdPerson AdLoggedOnPerson = new AdPerson();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

Comment: Is the build action of all your app_code files set to "Compile"?

Comment: Yes it is set to "Compile"

Answer (score 0):

So I had to change CodeBehind to CodeFile. I have no idea why this makes a difference but it worked.